# Installing ipmitool for Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssl, ipmi

I am trying to install ipmitool on Windows 10. I just installed Cygwin and have been trying to follow the steps for building ipmitool 1.8.12 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907005/ipmitool-for-windows), but I am having issues packaging the IPMI binary and related dlls into a zip file.

It was mentioned that Cygwin now uses OpenSSL 1.1 and the ipmitool 1.8.12 source code and Cygwin version in the previous set of instructions used OpenSSL 1.0.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58139836/9448627

Could anyone provide a new set of instructions on how to install ipmitool (latest version 1.1.18) on Windows?